# react-scripts build generates wrong path for sub folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, production, react-scripts, serve

My application should be served at `/sub-folder` so in the `package.json` the `homepage` field is set to

```
"homepage": "/sub-folder/",
```

The production bundle generated by `react-scripts build` is placed inside the `dist` directory that looks like

```
/dist
  /static
    /js
      main.[hash].js
      ...
    asset-manifest.json
    index.html
    ...
```

However `index.html` is trying to load at the following path

```
<script defer="defer" src="/sub-folder/static/js/main.41ee4874.js">
```

and obviously fails and won't load anything.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for it.

```
/ package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "BUILD_PATH='./sub-folder' react-scripts build",
    // ...
  },
```

Comment: It doesn't work. My `BUILD_PATH` is `./dist` and it won't affect the `src` property